# Less: second call of @font-face parametric mixin keeps values from first call

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, less

I try to include web fonts with LESS. The parametric mixin which partly does the job is the following:

```
.fontface(@fontName, @fontFile) { 
    @font-face { 
        font-family: @fontName;
        src: url("@{fontFile}.eot");    
        src: url("@{fontFile}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("@{fontFile}.woff") format('woff'),
        url("@{fontFile}.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("@{fontFile}.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal; } }
.font(@fontsize:10pt, @fontName:"Aierbazzi", @fontFile:"Aierbazzi-fontfacekit/aierbazzi-webfont") { 
        .fontface(@fontName, @fontFile);
font-family:@fontName;
font-size:@fontsize; }
```

It works fine being called the first time:

```
.font1 { .font(24pt, "Black-Rose","Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont"); }
.font4 { .font(24pt, "bubblegum-sans","bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont"); }
```

results in:

```
.font1 { 
    font-family:"Black-Rose";
    font-size:24pt; }
    @font-face { 
        font-family:"Black-Rose";
        src:url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot");
        src:url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.woff") format('woff'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal; }

.font4 { 
    font-family:"bubblegum-sans";
    font-size:24pt; }
    @font-face { 
        font-family:"Black-Rose";
        src:url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot");
        src:url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.woff") format('woff'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal; }
```

when I swap the 2 lines around:

```
.font4 { .font(24pt, "bubblegum-sans","bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont"); }
.font1 { .font(24pt, "Black-Rose","Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont"); }
```

again just the first web font is registered in the CSS:

```
.font4 { 
    font-family:"bubblegum-sans";
    font-size:24pt; } 
@font-face { 
    font-family:"bubblegum-sans";
    src:url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot");
    src:url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format('woff'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;}

.font1 { 
    font-family:"Black-Rose";
    font-size:24pt; }
@font-face { 
    font-family:"bubblegum-sans";
    src:url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot");
    src:url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format('woff'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal; }
```

What could be the reason? I am clueless in the moment.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Testing shows that once it enters the `@font-face` section, it somehow looses access to the local variable and _almost_ (though not quite) seems to treat it as if it were a global variable (and variables can only be set once within their scope in LESS). I have not found a workaround for it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on this current (as of my answer) bug](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/699), I used a solution a person posted there to modify your code. It creates the need for a replication of entering the `@fontName` so that you avoid passing a variable into `.fontface` call (which is now called from inside the `@font-face` block), but it does give the proper output:

**LESS**

```css
.fontface(@fontName:"Aierbazzi", @fontFile:"Aierbazzi-fontfacekit/aierbazzi-webfont")  {   
    font-family: @fontName;
    src: url("@{fontFile}.eot");    
    src: url("@{fontFile}.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("@{fontFile}.woff") format('woff'),
    url("@{fontFile}.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("@{fontFile}.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
} 

.font(@fontsize:10pt, @fontName:"Aierbazzi"){
    font-family:@fontName;
    font-size:@fontsize; 
}

.font1 { 
    .font(24pt, "Black-Rose");
    @font-face { 
       .fontface("Black-Rose","Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont");
    } 
}

.font4 { 
    .font(24pt, "bubblegum-sans");
    @font-face { 
        .fontface("bubblegum-sans","bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont");
    } 
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.font1 {
  font-family: "Black-Rose";
  font-size: 24pt;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Black-Rose";
  src: url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot");
  src: url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("Black-Rose-fontfacekit/BLACKR-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.font4 {
  font-family: "bubblegum-sans";
  font-size: 24pt;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "bubblegum-sans";
  src: url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot");
  src: url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("bubblegum-sans-fontfacekit/BubblegumSans-Regular-webfont.svg#DistantGalaxyRegular") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```