# LESSC @font-face error

Tags: node.js, less

I have a little LESS mixin for simplifying font face stuff

```
.fontface(@font){
    @font-face {
        font-family: '@{font}';
        src: url('../fonts/@{font}.eot');
        src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/@{font}.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/@{font}.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/@{font}.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

On my local computer (OS/X), running lessc on

```
.fontface(@font){
    @font-face {
        font-family: '@{font}';
        src: url('../fonts/@{font}.eot');
        src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/@{font}.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/@{font}.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/@{font}.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}

.fontface('MyFont');
.fontface('MyOtherFont');
```

returns

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../fonts/MyFont.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/MyFont.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyOtherFont';
  src: url('../fonts/MyOtherFont.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/MyOtherFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyOtherFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/MyOtherFont.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

however running it on our build server (CentOS 6.2) returns

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../fonts/MyFont.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/MyFont.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('../fonts/MyFont.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/MyFont.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Why are both mixins returning the same on our build server but working fine locally?

Both computers report the same less version.

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:Desktop sr$ lessc -v
lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]


[sr@egdjnk01 ~]$ lessc -v
lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

I've run `npm -g update less` on both, but I'm still receiving different behavior.

I think it's something to do with `@font-face`, if I remove that and replace it with a dummy class name the output is fine.

Comment: This could be related to the issue (and bug) I addressed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605277/less-second-call-of-font-face-parametric-mixin-keeps-values-from-first-call/11611715#11611715), though the fact that you are using the same version but getting two different results does make this more of an oddity. Anyway, I offer that as a possible help to resolve it.

Comment: @ScottS OK thanks, that's a work-around for now. My fonts are defined in one file I `@import` so it's not that much extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around for now, suggested by @ScottS in
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605277#11611715)
, is to put the `.fontface` mixin inside `@font-face` blocks manually defined, like so

```
.fontface(@font){
    font-family: '@{font}';
    src: url('../fonts/@{font}.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/@{font}.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/@{font}.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/@{font}.svg#webfont5SwbW1jA') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face{
    .fontface('MyFont');
}

@font-face{
    .fontface('MyOtherFont');
}
```

which now gives the correct output from both compilers.