# LESS CSS all text no longer showing

Tags: css, less, font-face

I recently started using LESS to make it easier to write styles for big projects but after changing my CSS to LESS, the text on my buttons, radio buttons, checkboxes, anchors and textareas have vanished, leaving them with only the padding. These elements all use embedded fonts (except the text inputs and textareas)

I'm not sure if the @font-face has anything to do with it but this is my LESS for that:

```
.-f-font(@name) {
    font-family: @name;
    src:~"url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.otf),url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.eot)";
}
.-f-font-Audimat {
    @font-face {
        .-f-font("Audimat");
    }
}
.-f-font-Jura {
    @font-face {
        .-f-font("Jura");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: The only font I see is Audimat.ttf. That one is specific for the button like elements.

Comment: The type for that however is "application/octet-stream".
Should it possibly be "font/ttf" instead?

Comment: I think you have similar issues to [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605277/less-second-call-of-font-face-parametric-mixin-keeps-values-from-first-call/11611715#11611715).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your CSS Output for your given code ***does not make the classes*** (`-f-font-Audimat` and `-f-font-Jura`) themselves, just the font-face blocks. So your code only is generating this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Audimat";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.otf),url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.eot);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Jura";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/Jura.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/Jura.otf),url(../assets/fonts/Jura.eot);
}
```

You can correct this two ways:

### Option 1

***Keep your mixin as you currently show it to be***, and add the `font-family` definition directly to the class definitions (disadvantage, it has repetition of code).

**LESS**

```
.-f-font-Audimat {
    font-family: "Audimat";
    @font-face {
        .-f-font("Audimat");
    }
}
.-f-font-Jura {
    font-family: "Jura";
    @font-face {
        .-f-font("Jura");
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.-f-font-Audimat {
  font-family: "Audimat";
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Audimat";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.otf),url(../assets/fonts/Audimat.eot);
}
.-f-font-Jura {
  font-family: "Jura";
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Jura";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/Jura.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/Jura.otf),url(../assets/fonts/Jura.eot);
}
```

### Option 2

Change your mixin to dynamically create all the font definition, including class names, and call the mixin without nesting (disadvantage, dynamically made classes in LESS currently cannot themselves be used as mixins). Like so:

**LESS**

```
.-f-font(@name) {
  @className: ~"@{name}";
  .-f-font-@{className} {
    font-family: @name;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: @name;
    src:~"url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.ttf),url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.otf),url(../assets/fonts/@{name}.eot)";
  }
}

.-f-font("Audimat");
.-f-font("Jura");
```

**CSS Output** - is the same as **Option #1**.

Comment: This hasn't necessarily fixed my problem with fonts not showing. It's strange, especially if I copy my LESS and convert it to CSS using less2css.org and use that instead, the fonts work. I may just go with a different preprocessor that is less buggy. Thank you though, your code is elegant.